# Rxjs Duplex Streams

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Is there any way with RxJs to create an Observable/Observer object that has logic for both receiving events and emitting events, similar to `Rx.Subject` except without combining the Observable and the Observer, so when events are emitted from inside the Observable's body, they aren't handled by the Observer body functions.

Something like this:

```
var someSystem = /* some system that receives and emits events */;

function someFn() {
  return ObservableObserver((observer, observable) => {
    observable.subscribe((e) => someSystem.emit(e));
    someSystem.on("data", (d) => observer.onNext(d));
  });
}

const mySystem = someFn();

mySystem.subscribe(
  (e) => {
    console.log("Received from 'someSystem':", e);
    mySystem.onNext("sending this to 'someSystem'");
  }
);
```

**Edit:**

I believe what I am looking for is similar to the Node.js Duplex Stream:

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_duplex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am following your requirement you can use the [`Subject#create`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/subject.md#rxsubjectcreateobserver-observable) method:

```
function someFn() {
  return Subject.create(
    Observer.create((e) => someSystem.emit(e)),
    Observable.fromEvent(someSystem, 'data')
  );
}

const mySystem = someFn()

source.subscribe(mySystem);

mySystem.subscribe((e) => {
  console.log("Received from 'someSystem':", e);
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!